# "error: break statement not within loop or switch" in arduino one

Tags: c++, arduino, tinkercad

i don´t have any idea of coding but i´m doing a school exersice and it gives me the error of the title

```
while (distancia<200 && distancia>100);
{

  lcd.print("ALTO");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  delay(1000);

  if(distancia<100)
  {

   break;
  }
}
 if(distancia<100);
  {

    lcd.print("INTRUSO EN");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("LA PUERTA");
    tone(11,700,250);
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    delay(500);
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    delay(500);
}
}
```

It is in arduino and I want that it returns to the first while if (100<distancia) and that ("ALTO") disapear when (distancia<100), pls help, I have no idea of what I´m doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
  while (distancia<200 && distancia>100);
  --------------------------------------^
```

remove that semicolon, it terminates the `while` right there

```
    while (distancia<200 && distancia>100)
```

Comment: Thank you, the error disaperar but now I have another clue. When (distancia<100) it stills showing the ("ALTO") instead of ("INTRUSO EN")

Comment: @AlanAlanis In the code snippet, I see `distancia` checked four times in different places, but nowhere changed. How and where is `distancia` supposed to be changed?

Comment: You probably should ask a completely new question for this completely different problem. This question was about the `break;` and the problem ended up being that you put an errant `;` on the while () line unknowingly ending the loop before you expected.

Comment: @heapunderrun this is not the full code. distancia is not suposed to apear but ("ALTO") and ("INTRUSO EN") appears in an lcd display. distancia is from an ultrasonic distance sensor in the arduino one